# awk is not producing the desired output

Tags: text-processing, awk

Below is my command output. When I process it through `awk`, it is giving unwanted output. What am I doing wrong?

```
# lvdisplay -m
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/Appsvg/apps01
  VG Name                Appsvg
  LV UUID                TckScf-LXdY-BvU1-NGhQ-5vUQ-KoNz-Uus1Of
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                15.00 GB
  Current LE             3840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extent 0 to 3839:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/emcpoweraq
    Physical extents    0 to 3839


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/Appsvg/apps02
  VG Name                Appsvg
  LV UUID                FcMopR-57MH-aTrT-3bq2-wUJZ-blEI-161Ivz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.00 GB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extent 0 to 2559:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/emcpoweraq
    Physical extents    3840 to 6399


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/Appsvg/apps03
  VG Name                Appsvg
  LV UUID                Ji4ldh-2ffZ-9qmb-BVaz-rwYd-f9HQ-2imPYG
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                20.00 GB
  Current LE             5120
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extent 0 to 5119:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/emcpoweraq
    Physical extents    6400 to 11519
```

```
# lvdisplay -m|awk '/(LV Name)/{l=$3} /(Physical volume)/{p=$3} {print l,p;}'

/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
................. output snipped.......
```

I am looking forward to see the "LV Name" & "Physical volume" only. This means one entry should be visible only one time. The output I am expecting is as below:

```
/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq
/dev/Appsvg/apps03 /dev/emcpoweraq
```

Comment: Can you clarify the output that you were expecting (by [editing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/243372/edit) your question to give an example)?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I need output sorted once for matched stringe while it is listing same output many times...if you will see the output of "lvdisplay -m" it should apear 3 times only as i have edited in my post the desired output ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm guessing correctly, you just need an extra set of curly braces to combine the last two statements (`p=$3` and `print l,p`):

```
                                                           /-     HERE    -\
                                                          \/               \/
lvdisplay -m | awk '/(LV Name)/{l=$3} /(Physical volume)/{{p=$3} {print l,p;}}'
```

To Ulrich Schwarz's comment, more obvious may be:

```
lvdisplay -m | awk '/(LV Name)/{l=$3} /(Physical volume)/{p=$3; print l,p;}'
```

The `awk` command from your question was assigning "l" and "p" as expected, but "print l,p" had no condition before it, so it was being executed on every line.

Comment: `p=$3; print l,p;` should do it fine, too.

Comment: [ @Jeff - You are correct.. can you explain it more..

# lvdisplay -m |awk '/(LV Name)/{l=$3} /(Physical volume)/{{p=$3} {print l,p;}}'

/dev/Appsvg/apps01 /dev/emcpoweraq

/dev/Appsvg/apps02 /dev/emcpoweraq

/dev/Appsvg/apps03 /dev/emcpoweraq  ]

Comment: @Linu I appended an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Or even: `awk '/LV Name/ {printf "%s%s", $NF, OFS}; /Physical volume/ {print $NF}'`